# How to select image src via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have HTML like this:

```
<div class="h5p-image">
  <img src="localhost/images/file-5fa55a3d758c4.jpg" alt="New image" title="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
</div>
```

and I want to select that image via src, so my JS looks like this:

```
var list= document.querySelectorAll('.h5p-image > img').src = "file-5fa55a3d758c4.jpg";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  list[i].style.width = "300px";
}
```

Error from the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length'
```

Can anybody try to help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list is either

`var list= document.querySelectorAll('.h5p-image > img')`

OR

`var list= document.querySelectorAll('.h5p-image > img[src$="5fa55a3d758c4.jpg"]')` (using ends-with)

assuming you have more than one div with that image.

So the code is likely this to style the div

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('.h5p-image > img[src$="5fa55a3d758c4.jpg"]')]
.forEach(img => img.closest("div").style.width = "300px");
```

or this to just style the image

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('.h5p-image > img[src$="5fa55a3d758c4.jpg"]')]
.forEach(img => img.style.width = "300px");
```

Or if there is only ONE image

```
document.querySelector('.h5p-image > img').style.width = "300px"
```

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.h5p-image > img[src$="758c4.jpg"]')]
.forEach(img => img.style.width = "300px");
```

```html
<div class="h5p-image">
  <img src="https://www.nice-premium.com/local/cache-vignettes/L600xH800/2012-03-19_08.53.13-758c4.jpg" alt="New image" title="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
</div>


<div class="h5p-image">
  <img src="https://www.nice-premium.com/local/cache-vignettes/L600xH800/2012-03-19_08.53.30-f371c.jpg" alt="New image" title="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
</div>


<div class="h5p-image">
  <img src="https://www.nice-premium.com/local/cache-vignettes/L600xH800/2012-03-19_08.53.13-758c4.jpg" alt="New image" title="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I got this error from the console " Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '.h5p-image > img[src*=file-5fa55a3d758c4.jpg]' is not a valid selector."

Comment: Still, " Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '.h5p-image > img[src$=5fa55a3d758c4.jpg]' is not a valid selector."